# Create New XCode Project With Existing Package Name

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, certificate

I am currently using Cordova (non CLI). I want to make a new Cordova project for the same code with CLI. If I make it with the same package name, will all the certificates transfer over and work with it? If I make an update to app on App Store will it work if I create this new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By package name, if you mean app ID then yes.